# Dockfile image build failing due to bundler issues and GemNotFoundException

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

The docker image "web" seems to fail as the image is built with the following error code:

```
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   2: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
web_1       |   1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
web_1       | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.2.24) required by your /prospector/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
web_1       | To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
web_1       | To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.2.24`
prospector_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Docker complains that it can't find the correct version of bundler, but you can see from the output below that I clearly do have the correct versions of bundler installed:

```
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % rvm --version
rvm 1.29.12-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % ruby --version
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin20]
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % bundle --version
Bundler version 2.2.24
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % which ruby
/Users/masonmings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % which bundle
/Users/masonmings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % bundler --version
Bundler version 2.2.24
masonmings@macbook-pro-10 prospector % which bundler
/Users/masonmings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundler
```

I've run the error message's suggested commands, but they don't help either. I've tried following the instructions on [this page][1], [this page][2], [this page][3], and several others but can't seem to find this issue solved online. I've also uninstalled, removed, and rebundled everything. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's some more context:

The docker-compose.yml file for this image is as follows:

```
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile-web
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    # command: tail -f /dev/null # Keeps container running
    volumes:
      - ./:/prospector
      - ./tmp/bundle:/bundle # Gem cache
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 # Server
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - selenium
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true # Allows attaching for byebug
    tty: true # Allows attaching for byebug
```

### Dockerfile-web looks like this:

```
###
# Dockerfile for web service, which is effectively our Rails app
#
# Based on: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project

# Use Ruby 2.6.5 Image
FROM ruby:2.6.5

# Install essentials
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev

# Install NodeJS
# https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Copy contents into
RUN mkdir /prospector
WORKDIR /prospector
COPY ./ /app

# Set entrypoint script, required for caching gems (so not to have redownload & rebuild every build)
# See https://medium.com/@cristian_rivera/cache-rails-bundle-w-docker-compose-45512d952c2d
COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint-web.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-web.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint-web.sh"]

# Set env variables for caching gems
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin
ENV GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV PATH="${BUNDLE_BIN}:${PATH}"
```

---

### .zshrc looks like this:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

export Path="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm"
```

---

### .bashrc looks like this:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm"

export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")
```

---

The output of bundle env is:

---

### Environment

```
Bundler             2.2.24

  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-darwin-20

Ruby                2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin20]

  Full Path         /Users/masonmings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby

  Config Dir        /Users/masonmings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/etc

RubyGems            3.2.24

  Gem Home          /Users/masonmings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5

  Gem Path          /Users/masonmings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5:/Users/masonmings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

  User Home         /Users/masonmings

  User Path         /Users/masonmings/.gem/ruby/2.6.0

  Bin Dir           /Users/masonmings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin

Tools               

  Git               2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

  RVM               1.29.12-next (master)

  rbenv             not installed

  chruby            not installed

  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2021-07-15

Git SHA           d78b1ee235

Released Version  true
```

### Bundler settings

```
cache_all

  Set for your local app (/Users/masonmings/Camber Code/prospector/.bundle/config): true
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'



# Application

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3' # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0' # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record

gem 'puma', '~> 3.11' # Use Puma as the app server

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' # Use SCSS for stylesheets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5' # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5' # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0' # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false # Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb

gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.7' # Simple, efficient background processing for Ruby.



# Data

gem 'enumerize', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.1' # Enums / Enumerated attributes with I18n

gem 'rails-settings-cached', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.3' # Settings plugin for Rails that makes managing a table of global key, value pairs easy

gem 'chronic', '~> 0.10.2' # Natural language date/time parser

gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1' # Cclean, powerful, agnostic, customizable and sophisticated paginator



# UI

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1' # Bootstrap, as we all know too well

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3' # JQuery for Rails

gem 'rouge', '~> 3.7' # Code highlighter



# Authentication 

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9' # OmniAuth is a flexible authentication system utilizing Rack middleware 

gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2' # A Google OAuth2 strategy for OmniAuth 1.x. This allows you to login to Google



# Services

gem 'google-cloud-bigquery' # Google Big Query

gem 'sentry-raven' # Sentry exception monitoring service

gem 'pipedrive.rb', github: 'amoniacou/pipedrive.rb', ref: '1000a6f' # Pipedrive.com API Wrapper



# Utility

gem 'dotenv-rails' # Load environment variables from `.env`

gem 'httparty', '~> 0.17.0' # Makes http fun again!

gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.5' # Annotates Rails/ActiveRecord Models

gem 'net-ssh', '~> 5.2' # Pure Ruby implementation of the SSH2 client protocol

gem 'highline', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2' # A high level command-line oriented interface



# Scraping

gem 'watir', '~> 6.16', '>= 6.16.5' # Interact with browsers the same way people do!

gem 'watir-webdriver-performance' # Collects and summarises metrics for Watir

gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15' # Acceptance test framework for web applications

gem 'selenium-webdriver' # A browser automation framework and ecosystem

gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0' # Keep your Selenium WebDrivers updated automatically



# Development & Test

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw] # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console

  gem 'pry'

end



# Development

group :development do

  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11', require: false # Utility and framework for executing commands in parallel via SSH (read: deploying)

  gem 'capistrano-decompose', github: 'Whelton/capistrano-decompose', ref: '030b9c5' # Capistrano plugin to deploy your application inside docker containers with docker compose

  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0' # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.

  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2' # Listens to file modifications and notifies you about the changes

  gem 'spring' # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring

  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0' # Spring x Listen

end
```

#### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT

  remote: https://github.com/Whelton/capistrano-decompose.git

  revision: 030b9c5b96ef03d411aa1a9de661e4ef2041bff1

  ref: 030b9c5

  specs:

    capistrano-decompose (0.2.0)

      capistrano (~> 3.5)



GIT

  remote: https://github.com/amoniacou/pipedrive.rb.git

  revision: 1000a6f930a55ad81d96f876478c6fc3bf38a28a

  ref: 1000a6f

  specs:

    pipedrive.rb (0.1.0)

      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

      faraday

      faraday_middleware

      hashie (>= 3.0)



GEM

  remote: https://rubygems.org/

  specs:

    actioncable (5.2.6)

      actionpack (= 5.2.6)

      nio4r (~> 2.0)

      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)

    actionmailer (5.2.6)

      actionpack (= 5.2.6)

      actionview (= 5.2.6)

      activejob (= 5.2.6)

      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)

      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)

    actionpack (5.2.6)

      actionview (= 5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)

      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)

      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)

      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

    actionview (5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      builder (~> 3.1)

      erubi (~> 1.4)

      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)

      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)

    activejob (5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      globalid (>= 0.3.6)

    activemodel (5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

    activerecord (5.2.6)

      activemodel (= 5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      arel (>= 9.0)

    activestorage (5.2.6)

      actionpack (= 5.2.6)

      activerecord (= 5.2.6)

      marcel (~> 1.0.0)

    activesupport (5.2.6)

      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)

      minitest (~> 5.1)

      tzinfo (~> 1.1)

    addressable (2.8.0)

      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)

    airbrussh (1.4.0)

      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)

    annotate (2.7.5)

      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 7.0)

      rake (>= 10.4, < 13.0)

    arel (9.0.0)

    autoprefixer-rails (10.2.5.1)

      execjs (> 0)

    bindex (0.8.1)

    bootsnap (1.7.5)

      msgpack (~> 1.0)

    bootstrap (4.6.0)

      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)

      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)

      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)

    builder (3.2.4)

    byebug (11.1.3)

    capistrano (3.16.0)

      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)

      i18n

      rake (>= 10.0.0)

      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)

    capybara (3.35.3)

      addressable

      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)

      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

      rack (>= 1.6.0)

      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)

      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)

      xpath (~> 3.2)

    childprocess (3.0.0)

    chronic (0.10.2)

    coderay (1.1.3)

    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)

    connection_pool (2.2.5)

    crass (1.0.6)

    declarative (0.0.20)

    dotenv (2.7.6)

    dotenv-rails (2.7.6)

      dotenv (= 2.7.6)

      railties (>= 3.2)

    enumerize (2.4.0)

      activesupport (>= 3.2)

    erubi (1.10.0)

    execjs (2.8.1)

    faraday (1.5.1)

      faraday-em_http (~> 1.0)

      faraday-em_synchrony (~> 1.0)

      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)

      faraday-httpclient (~> 1.0.1)

      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)

      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.1)

      faraday-patron (~> 1.0)

      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)

      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)

    faraday-em_http (1.0.0)

    faraday-em_synchrony (1.0.0)

    faraday-excon (1.1.0)

    faraday-httpclient (1.0.1)

    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)

    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.2.0)

    faraday-patron (1.0.0)

    faraday_middleware (1.0.0)

      faraday (~> 1.0)

    ffi (1.15.3)

    globalid (0.4.2)

      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    google-apis-bigquery_v2 (0.15.0)

      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)

    google-apis-core (0.4.1)

      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)

      googleauth (>= 0.16.2, < 2.a)

      httpclient (>= 2.8.1, < 3.a)

      mini_mime (~> 1.0)

      representable (~> 3.0)

      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.a)

      rexml

      webrick

    google-cloud-bigquery (1.34.0)

      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)

      google-apis-bigquery_v2 (~> 0.1)

      google-cloud-core (~> 1.6)

      googleauth (>= 0.16.2, < 2.a)

      mini_mime (~> 1.0)

    google-cloud-core (1.6.0)

      google-cloud-env (~> 1.0)

      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)

    google-cloud-env (1.5.0)

      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)

    google-cloud-errors (1.1.0)

    googleauth (0.16.2)

      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)

      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)

      memoist (~> 0.16)

      multi_json (~> 1.11)

      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)

      signet (~> 0.14)

    hashie (4.1.0)

    highline (2.0.3)

    httparty (0.17.3)

      mime-types (~> 3.0)

      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)

    httpclient (2.8.3)

    i18n (1.8.10)

      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)

    jbuilder (2.11.2)

      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)

    jquery-rails (4.4.0)

      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)

      railties (>= 4.2.0)

      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)

    jwt (2.2.3)

    kaminari (1.2.1)

      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.1)

      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.1)

      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)

    kaminari-actionview (1.2.1)

      actionview

      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)

    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.1)

      activerecord

      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)

    kaminari-core (1.2.1)

    listen (3.1.5)

      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)

      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)

      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)

    loofah (2.10.0)

      crass (~> 1.0.2)

      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)

    mail (2.7.1)

      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)

    marcel (1.0.1)

    memoist (0.16.2)

    method_source (1.0.0)

    mime-types (3.3.1)

      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)

    mime-types-data (3.2021.0704)

    mini_mime (1.1.0)

    mini_portile2 (2.5.3)

    minitest (5.14.4)

    msgpack (1.4.2)

    multi_json (1.15.0)

    multi_xml (0.6.0)

    multipart-post (2.1.1)

    net-scp (3.0.0)

      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, < 7.0.0)

    net-ssh (5.2.0)

    nio4r (2.5.7)

    nokogiri (1.11.7)

      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)

      racc (~> 1.4)

    oauth2 (1.4.7)

      faraday (>= 0.8, < 2.0)

      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)

      multi_json (~> 1.3)

      multi_xml (~> 0.5)

      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)

    omniauth (1.9.1)

      hashie (>= 3.4.6)

      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)

    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.8.2)

      jwt (>= 2.0)

      oauth2 (~> 1.1)

      omniauth (~> 1.1)

      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.6)

    omniauth-oauth2 (1.7.1)

      oauth2 (~> 1.4)

      omniauth (>= 1.9, < 3)

    os (1.1.1)

    pg (1.2.3)

    popper_js (1.16.0)

    pry (0.14.1)

      coderay (~> 1.1)

      method_source (~> 1.0)

    public_suffix (4.0.6)

    puma (3.12.6)

    racc (1.5.2)

    rack (2.2.3)

    rack-protection (2.1.0)

      rack

    rack-test (1.1.0)

      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)

    rails (5.2.6)

      actioncable (= 5.2.6)

      actionmailer (= 5.2.6)

      actionpack (= 5.2.6)

      actionview (= 5.2.6)

      activejob (= 5.2.6)

      activemodel (= 5.2.6)

      activerecord (= 5.2.6)

      activestorage (= 5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      bundler (>= 1.3.0)

      railties (= 5.2.6)

      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)

    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)

      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

      nokogiri (>= 1.6)

    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)

      loofah (~> 2.3)

    rails-settings-cached (2.7.1)

      rails (>= 5.0.0)

    railties (5.2.6)

      actionpack (= 5.2.6)

      activesupport (= 5.2.6)

      method_source

      rake (>= 0.8.7)

      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)

    rake (12.3.3)

    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)

    rb-inotify (0.10.1)

      ffi (~> 1.0)

    redis (4.1.4)

    regexp_parser (2.1.1)

    representable (3.1.1)

      declarative (< 0.1.0)

      trailblazer-option (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2.0)

      uber (< 0.2.0)

    retriable (3.1.2)

    rexml (3.2.5)

    rouge (3.26.0)

    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)

    ruby_dep (1.5.0)

    rubyzip (2.3.2)

    sass (3.7.4)

      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)

    sass-listen (4.0.0)

      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)

      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)

    sass-rails (5.1.0)

      railties (>= 5.2.0)

      sass (~> 3.1)

      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)

      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)

    sassc (2.4.0)

      ffi (~> 1.9)

    sassc-rails (2.1.2)

      railties (>= 4.0.0)

      sassc (>= 2.0)

      sprockets (> 3.0)

      sprockets-rails

      tilt

    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)

      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)

      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)

    sentry-raven (3.1.2)

      faraday (>= 1.0)

    sidekiq (5.2.9)

      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)

      rack (~> 2.0)

      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)

      redis (>= 3.3.5, < 4.2)

    signet (0.15.0)

      addressable (~> 2.3)

      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)

      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)

      multi_json (~> 1.10)

    spring (2.1.1)

    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)

      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)

      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)

    sprockets (3.7.2)

      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)

      rack (> 1, < 3)

    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)

      actionpack (>= 4.0)

      activesupport (>= 4.0)

      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)

    sshkit (1.21.2)

      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)

      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)

    thor (1.1.0)

    thread_safe (0.3.6)

    tilt (2.0.10)

    trailblazer-option (0.1.1)

    turbolinks (5.2.1)

      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)

    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)

    tzinfo (1.2.9)

      thread_safe (~> 0.1)

    uber (0.1.0)

    uglifier (4.2.0)

      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)

    watir (6.19.1)

      regexp_parser (>= 1.2, < 3)

      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.142.7)

    watir-webdriver (0.9.9)

      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.46.2)

    watir-webdriver-performance (0.2.4)

      watir-webdriver

    web-console (3.7.0)

      actionview (>= 5.0)

      activemodel (>= 5.0)

      bindex (>= 0.4.0)

      railties (>= 5.0)

    webdrivers (4.6.0)

      nokogiri (~> 1.6)

      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)

      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)

    webrick (1.7.0)

    websocket-driver (0.7.5)

      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)

    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)

    xpath (3.2.0)

      nokogiri (~> 1.8)



PLATFORMS

  ruby



DEPENDENCIES

  annotate (~> 2.7, >= 2.7.5)

  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)

  bootstrap (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.1)

  byebug

  capistrano (~> 3.11)

  capistrano-decompose!

  capybara (>= 2.15)

  chronic (~> 0.10.2)

  dotenv-rails

  enumerize (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.1)

  google-cloud-bigquery

  highline (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)

  httparty (~> 0.17.0)

  jbuilder (~> 2.5)

  jquery-rails (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.3)

  kaminari (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)

  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)

  net-ssh (~> 5.2)

  omniauth (~> 1.9)

  omniauth-google-oauth2

  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)

  pipedrive.rb!

  pry

  puma (~> 3.11)

  rails (~> 5.2.3)

  rails-settings-cached (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.3)

  rouge (~> 3.7)

  sass-rails (~> 5.0)

  selenium-webdriver

  sentry-raven

  sidekiq (~> 5.2, >= 5.2.7)

  spring

  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)

  turbolinks (~> 5)

  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

  watir (~> 6.16, >= 6.16.5)

  watir-webdriver-performance

  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

  webdrivers (~> 4.0)



RUBY VERSION

   ruby 2.6.5p114



BUNDLED WITH

   2.2.24


...


  [1]: https://bundler.io/doc/troubleshooting.html
  [2]: https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html
  [3]: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1138
```

Comment: You need to install the _exact_ version of Bundler listed in the `Gemfile.lock` in your Dockerfile; it doesn't matter what you have on your host, and the dotfiles you list don't get used at all.  Since Bundler 2.1.0 every version of Bundler is a major release that refuses to work with a `Gemfile.lock` created with any other Bundler version.

Comment: (For the sake of simplifying this setup, I might remove the Node installation from the Dockerfile [and use a multi-stage build if you have a front-end component that needs to be precompiled]; move the `command:` to a Dockerfile `CMD` and remove the Compose `volumes:`, so the image is self-contained and can run itself; remove the obsolete Compose `links:`; and potentially move the `Dockerfile` to the top level of your repository.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the help. Are the Gemfile.lock and Dockerfiles not using the same version of Bundler? From what I can tell, everything seems to be using Bundler 2.2.24. What file should I go to to help sort out this issue?